# PHP Weird Syntax - What is it called?

Tags: php, syntax, content-management-system, conditional-statements

I've been following a video series about a PHP framework and I've come across a weird construct. I'd just like to find out what it's called so I can read up on it some more. In the video, the speaker gives this code

```
public function edit($id = NULL)
{
   $id == NULL || $this->data['user'] = $this->user_m->get($id);
   ...
}
```

He says, if the caller passes no id, then the $id will set to null, if an $id is passed, the user will be retrieved from the database and saved in the data array.

Thing is, this is a conditional statement, but it's not inside an if or while or something like that. I've never seen that before. I've searched for inline or, conditional outside a loop/if statement, weird syntax with no success. Like I said, I'd like to read up more about it and find out whether it's a general PHP feature or framework-specific.

Thanks.

Comment: that's a ternary operator. Nothing more and nothing left, the right hand evaluation though is not that popular, I personally don't like it. As far as I know it is the exact same as: `$id !== NULL && $this->data['user'] = $this->user_m->get($id);` or, more readable: `$this->data['user'] = $id == NULL ? $this->user_m->get($id) : $this->data['user'];` In a nutshell, it basically says "If id is not null (or, more precisely, if $id == null is **falsey**), then set this->data['user'] to this->user_m->get($id), else just keep $id null and move on.

Comment: @b0s3: No, just guessing, I'm used to these, what is only bothering me is the parameter passed to the function, I assume it is $id = null rather than id == null, else It shouldn't even compile, right?

Comment: It MUST be $id = null, else it will result as a parse error, but again, I think that the question is about the ternary operator, not about why it is passing $id == null, hence I just think it is either a parse error inside the code or just an error while copying some code. In any case, confirmed, $id == null in the condition will just screw everything up.

Comment: No ternary operator is used in the posted source code...

Comment: @Seb : Technically, it also can be considered as a ternary operator, or seen as a ternary operator, or interpreted and rewritten as a ternary operator.

Comment: No, there is no ternary operator involved right now... an OR clearly is a binary operator.

Comment: @Seb: In this case, the OR is a **logical OR** operator ( `||` ), not a **or binary operator** (`|`). You're still performing logical operations so take your conclusions out of that.

Comment: @briosheje: unary = single argument, binary = two arguments, ternary = three arguments... I don't see any contradiction in my statement.

Comment: @Sethmo011: You should edit the question and remove the syntax error in the method signature.

Comment: Thanks, Seb, didn't notice that...it's not supposed to be an equality check...will do

Comment: Just experimented with something and it seems, even if the entire evaluation returns false, the code underneath still runs! So it seems it's handy as a shortcut to an if to assign a value to a variable, but if you get it wrong, must be a pain to debug!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sytnax is called "short-circuit evaluation" and is an optimization technique used in most programming languages. The right expression of an `||` is only evaluated if the left expression is false, because -otherwise- the result does not depend on the value of the right expression (as the right expression of an `&&` is only evaluated if the left one is true).

You could rewrite your example to `($id == NULL) || ($this->data['user'] = $this->user_m->get($id));` to make it more clear. The assignment expression is only evaluated, if `$id` is not `NULL`.

However, this line of code is a perfect example for code that is hard to maintain, because you need to spend way to much time thinking about what it does... :)

Comment: So, it's effectively almost like shorthand for a ternary operator? I agree with your sentiments about it being hard to maintain. I could understand what it did, I just didn't know that it could be done that way.

Answer (score 1):

To create the proper answer to this question, we must start by saying that there probably (I would say probably, because I'm still not 100% sure about that) an error in your function syntax:

```
public function edit($id == NULL)
```

should be:

```
public function edit($id = NULL)
```

Which would totally makes sense with the rest of the code, because it will set the **local variable ID** to NULL if it is not set, else it will set it.

That said, the rest, as said in the comments, is just an OR logical operation (Fine, see that in whatever way you want, I'm used to interprete it as a ternary operator, because it's slighty easier if someone doesn't know how it works), I just feel that I should point out that differently from many other languages, in PHP you can directly evaluate a variable in the second or third or whatever parameter of logical operations.

In a nutshell, your operations:

```
$id == NULL || $this->data['user'] = $this->user_m->get($id);
```

could be also written as:

```
if ($id !== null) {
   $this->data['user'] = $this->user_m->get($id);
}
```

Which is readable, of course, else, you could also do:

```
$id !== NULL && $this->data['user'] = $this->user_m->get($id);
```

Or even:

```
$this->data['user'] = $id !== NULL ? $this->user_m->get($id) : $this->data['user'];
```

The basic ternary operator is:

```
condition ? iftrue : iffalse
```

The "variation" you have is rather a sort of "use" of logical operations, called **short-circuit evaluation**, in fact, the OR logical operator evaluates the right hand operator ONLY IF THE LEFT HAND ONE IS FALSEY, hence:

```
$id == NULL || $this->data['user'] = $this->user_m->get($id);
```

`$id == NULL` <-- left hand operator

`$this->data['user'] = $this->user_m->get($id)` <-- right hand operator

taking what we said above, **if $id == NULL is falsey**, (that means, if $id is not null), then execute the right hand operator, so set $this->data['user'] to $this->user_m->get($id), otherwise do nothing at all.

Comment: It is not a ternary operator. It is boolean `or`.

Comment: I've provided many interpretation of the really same thing but ok, fine, let's say it's just a boolean or, and let's see if it is clearer to say that it is a boolean or just something that can be interpreted as a sort of short-hand if. I think it would've rather been better to point out that $id == NULL as a parameter will **never** compile instead of that.

Comment: Of course, you can rewrite the code to say something else... however, this changes the question. The semantic of the original code in the question is what I answered, there is not a single ternary operator involved.

Comment: @Seb: Did you read my answer or just downvoted it for the purpose of the ternary operator? Besides, interprete it in whatever way you want but it still the same exact thing, the OP needs to understand what it is and I've provided a full explanation of what it is, what could've been and what is the real meaning, pointing out the most important thing which is that you really cannot compile his code as it is, because it has a parse error in it. Also, it would be worth mentioning that **not every language support the direct evaluation on the right hand operator**, which makes it ternary anyway.

Comment: I read your answer and I think it is misleading and not helpful if you would like to understand the concept. I agree that there is a syntax error, but it is unrelated to the question and the OP can easily fix it.

Comment: @Seb : So unrelated that it won't allow the OP to execute its code. In any case, feel free to interprete / do whatever you want, I will keep this answer for the guys in the future who will be interested in what is the real meaning of these shorthand operations, perhaps they will also find out that they are not that hard to mantain, if simple enough like this one :)

Comment: Also, taking from wikipedia directly: _Similar to PHP's short-hand operator, JavaScript programmers have long used the OR operator, which functionally produces the same results, (although, this type of "short-hand" is technically considered a null coalescing operator). See below: var aVar = bVar || cVar; // equivalent to `var aVar = bVar ? bVar : cVar`_ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F: Just saying.

Comment: My final comment: Think about that code snippet in terms of an abstract syntax tree. The OR takes two expressions, not three.

Comment: My final comment: Think about the fact that wikipedia is there from years, and that both the operations produces the same exact output.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, my function parameter was wrong. I understood what it meant, I also thought it was along the lines of a ternary operator when I first saw it, but the syntax was just so different to what I'd encountered before, I just wondered if it was in fact a ternary operator or if it was something else completely. Now I know, I've read up on it a bit more. I'm sure there's a time and a place to use it over the ternary or if statement.

Comment: @Sethmo011: It largely depends on your style and your own preferences: I personally use short-hand operators a lot, the OR logical operator is very useful when you need to set up a variable to avoid unexpected errors. In this case I personally think that a clearer ternary operator would've been way better than that, but if you need, for example, to set a default value to $id, for example, you can easily: $id = $id || 1; <-- this will set ID to 1 if $id is falsey (null is falsey). In a nutshell, these are not hard to mantain as long as they don't grow up in complexity.

Comment: Ja, using shorthand in the way you described makes a bit more sense. I do a lot of coding in a trading program and I've written giant systems and my experience is, saving a few lines of code like that usually ends in tears. I'm sure, like using things like anonymous functions and the like, once one has their head around it, it makes sense, but I'm thinking when I'm in a situation where I've been looking at a screen for hours and I don't know why a variable isn't setting correctly, I'd rather see a ternary operator or, at worst, an if statement. But, that's me.